# ControlChannelTrigger in UWP Windows 10 access denied

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am trying to implement background task with ControlChannelTrigger using WebSockets. In MSDN example I get an exception while running on Windows 10 Desktop in this place:

```
channel = new ControlChannelTrigger(channelId, serverKeepAliveInterval,ControlChannelTriggerResourceType)
```

Exception is "Access denied"

However in Windows 10 mobile this line passes and I get an exception Access Denied in the last line of the following block:

```
channel.UsingTransport(socket);   
var uri = new Uri(url);          
await socket.ConnectAsync(uri);
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Make sure you have called BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync() and lock screen is enabled. And check your appxmenifest. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj662740.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj676799.aspx is not dedicated for win10 uwp, but it is same for win10 uwp.

Comment: Yes I've done all of this. Can you confirm that it's working for you ?