# UWP network communication in the background

Tags: c#, push-notification, uwp, background-process, background-task

I'm trying to go through the official tutorial for background task network in UWP  titled [Network communications in the background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/network-communications-in-the-background#feedback). However, since the tutorial is poorly ported from C++ code, the code, after being modified to be able to compile, fails at instantiating the `ControlChannelTrigger` object with an `AccessDenied` exception.

The exception is thrown at the following line.

```
channel = new ControlChannelTrigger(channelId, serverKeepAliveInterval,
                                    ControlChannelTriggerResourceType.RequestHardwareSlot);
```

I read the comment about the lock screen and tried to add the app to the lock screen (even though this should no longer be a limitation), but the error persists.

I'm trying to maintain a persistent `WebSocket` connection with my own server to allow push notifications (I am aware of WNS, but it is not the right choice for my use-case).

My problem is similar to one in the related question [ControlChannelTrigger in UWP Windows 10 access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421747/controlchanneltrigger-in-uwp-windows-10-access-denied?rq=1).

For simplicity, I am implementing everything as an in-process background task.

Can anyone suggest a solution or a workaround? Could the tutorial be outdated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, I found the answer to my own question again.

The registered background task cannot be an in-process task and must be registered as an out-of-process task.

As for the `Windows.Networking.Sockets.WebSocketKeepAlive` entry point, I made a workaround by creating a background task that contained the `Windows.Networking.Sockets.WebSocketKeepAlive` and called its `Run(…)` method.